# Change the Text of Button in jqxgrid

Tags: jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

Hi friends is there a way to change the Text of Jqxgrid button??

I have a grid in which i am showing Active Records and In Active Records depending on the selection of a HTML drop down !!

If i select the 'Active' option in HTML drop down i am showing Active Recorders in the grid.
Where as
If i select the 'In Active' in HTML drop down i am showing In Active Recorders in grid.

When i am showing Active Recorders i am showing a button also in grid with text 'Remove' ,
 so at the time of Showing In Active recorders this button text should change to 'Add'

Please give me any references or working examples..????

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the name of the button text via the `cellsrenderer` function like so:

```
cellsrenderer:  function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
               var rowData = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
             if(rowData.productname == 'Cappuccino'){
                     return "Product Name is Cappuccino";
             }else{
                 return "Not Cappucino";
             }
         }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/35kU5/67/